# How to use RxJS for remote calls and how to explore the response to my View Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, superagent

I have a React-Native Android App where i am starting to fetch some remote Api data into my application. I thought to using RxJS together with super-agent (fetch() didn´t work in my code) and than distribute it to my Component Views.

Now this is my **super-agent POST method in my ApiHandler class** where i pass a username and password and getting a token:

```
tokenPOST: function ( email, password, props, navigator ) {
    rxRequest (
        request
            .post(BASE_URL + 'tokens')
            .type('json')
            .send({
                email:    email,
                password: password
            })
    )
        .doOnNext(function ( res ) {
            notifyMessage (res.token)
        })
        .subscribe(function ( res ) {
                var token = JSON.parse(res.text).token; // working

                navigator.replace({
                    id:   'MainController',
                    // maybe pass props with token here?!
                });
            },
            function ( err ) {
                notifyMessage ("Please check credentials again!")
            })
},
```

**Here is my RxJS Observable Code:**

```
var rxRequest = Rx.Observable.fromSuperagent = function ( request ) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    request.end(( err, res ) => {
        if (err) {
            observer.onError(err)
        } else {
            observer.onNext(res);
        }
        observer.onCompleted();
    })
  });
};
```

Now how do i actually pass the token result/response i get, which works, to my Component View?
I am new in react-native and RxJS, actually i am new in the whole JavaScript/ReactJS thing, so i would really appreciate it getting help.